# Making a Latin font smaller than Hebrew (unicode-range)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, hebrew, unicode-range

I have a Hebrew/English site that uses two fonts added with `@font-face`.
Using `unicode-range` I've defined one font to apply only at Hebrew chars and another to apply to all other chars.

The problem is in the fact that my Hebrew font has characters that look noticeably smaller than the ones in the Latin font. 
The easy solution would be to replace one of the fonts and find some other which has chars of a similar size. But unfortunately, I have to keep those two fonts. Can't change them.
So my question is. Is there a way to e.g. define that all chars in Latin unicode-range should have a `font-size` of `0.8em`?

Keep in mind that an element might contain both Hebrew and Latin chars at the same time. So a solution with setting a different class based on the entire site's language would not work. It would really have to be defined on the "per-char" level.

**Edit:** per request in comment I'm adding a code example:

```
/* --- --- --- Defining font: --- --- --- */
@font-face {
  font-family: HebrewFontName;

  src: local('HebrewFontName'),
  local('HebrewFontName'),
  url(/fonts/HebrewFontName.otf);
  font-weight: 300;
  unicode-range: U+0590-05FF,
  U+0030-0039;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: HelveticaNeue;

  src: url(/fonts/HelveticaNeueDeskUI-01.ttf);
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* --- --- --- Using font: --- --- --- */
.someElement {
  font-family: 'MigdalRegular', 'HelveticaNeue';
}
```

Comment: can you show some of your code please

Comment: Added code @לבנימלכה

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently.

The `unicode-range` property is intended for determining either to download a font or not. It doesn't filter the character range to apply the font to.

> ... If the page doesn't use any character in this range, the font is not downloaded; if it uses at least one, the whole font is downloaded.
>
> The purpose of this descriptor is to allow the font resources to be segmented so that a browser only needs to download the font resource needed for the text content of a particular page. For example, a site with many localizations could provide separate font resources for English, Greek and Japanese. For users viewing the English version of a page, the font resources for Greek and Japanese fonts wouldn't need to be downloaded, saving bandwidth.
>
> –– [MDN unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range)

Your best bet is to use different font for different language segment: by inserting `span` on the segments.